# What are channels in British repeaters?

Tags: repeater, united-kingdom

British repeaters seem to have a channel associated with them, something like RV53 in this repeater: https://ukrepeater.net/my_repeater.php?id=2817

What is that?

Are frequencies channelized in the UK? All repeaters on the same channel seem to have the same frequency: https://ukrepeater.net/my_channel.php?channel=RV53

The reason I'm asking is because I'm making a repeater database and I want to know what to do with that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, UK repeater frequencies are channelized; while our licences don't require us to use specific channels, Ofcom (regulator) has delegated repeater co-ordination to the RSGB (equivalent of ARRL in the USA) Emerging Technology Coordination Committee.

The ETCC, in turn, is responsible for ensuring that repeaters don't interfere with each other, which involves considering propagation and thus likely signal strength of a repeater; the goal is to ensure that a "standard" setup like a handheld won't key up two repeaters at once when transmitting, won't interfere with someone trying to key up a different repeater, and won't hear two repeaters on the same frequency. To make this easier, they use a set of [repeater channels](https://ukrepeater.net/channel_list.html) to ensure that there's never a "half way" overlap - repeaters are either on the same channel, a neighbouring channel, or shouldn't apply to this application.

There's a full guide at https://ukrepeater.net/doc_files/GuidetoRepeaterandGatewayLicensing.pdf to getting a repeater licensed in the UK; it includes an explanation of how they use a propagation model to determine which frequencies they can assign to your repeater without interference with other repeaters.

Comment: Seems like it's pretty much for the convenience of the frequency coordinators and the repeater operators though, people just *using* the repeater use the same information they would anywhere :)

Comment: It is mostly for the convenience of frequency coordination now. Back in the day, it also helped radio design - you had one crystal per frequency you could use, so channels limited the number of crystals a manufacturer needed to make

Answer (score 1):

There are several informative apps for UK repeater frequencies. My most used is, Repeater book. It list's all repeater operator's. Including codes, frequencies & offsets etc. It can be tailored so the one's positioned nearest your location appear first. This app helped me much more than i can express here. As i was a total noob to the scene. And the learning curve felt insurmountable. This allowed me to take small steps to begin my journey into Ham radio.

Comment: Thank you for your response Snowy and welcome to Ham Stack Exchange. I'm actually making a new app similar to that one called Repeater World: https://repeater.world. But when I'm importing the data from ukrepeaters.net, there's a "channel", which surprised me, so I was asking what that was about.

Answer (score 0):

RSGB provides a list of "channels": https://ukrepeater.net/channel_list.html

Comment: hi there. That’s just a list of channels from the website OP already linked to, and doesn’t really answer the question about the purpose of channels in the UK. Maybe you’d consider updating your answer to more directly answer the question.